# rich snippets appears in testing tool but not in search results

Tags: search, rich-snippets

i made some rich snippets in my website, I helped myself with all the google recomandations and after i made this, this appears in the google search results like it is shown in the rich snippet testing tool.
But for now i don't change anything, in the rich snippet testing tool it appears just right but it's not appearing in the google search results.

The url is http://www.formation-sketchup-pro.fr/ and i want the result when someone type "formation sketchup". Before it worked but not know, and i don't know why because in the testing tool it appears just right. Someone have an idea why ?